# Cin in recursive function

Tags: c++, iostream

Why does this thing keep looping ? .. I tried clearing the cin stream but still it loops if i enter something other than a number.

```
void AskQuestion()
{
    DisplayQuestion();
    bool Exit = false;
    int input = 0;
    cout<<"Input : ";
    if(!(cin>>input))
    {
        cout<<"Invalid Input"<<endl;
        cin.ignore(10000,'\n');
        cin.clear();
    }
    else
    {
        Exit = ProcessInput(input);
    }
    if(!Exit) AskQuestion();
}
```

Comment: Ok it works when i put clear before ignore but can anyone tell me why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, don't use recursion: make it a `while`.

Secondly, use sync:

```
int number;
while (true) {
    if (cin >> number)
        break;
    cout << "Invalid number.\n";
    cin.sync();
    cin.clear();
}
cout << "Number: " << number;
```

Comment: I want to display an invalid input and then recall the function again if cin fails. how will i achieve it using while?

Comment: Put your call to DisplayQuestion() and the message asking for the input inside the loop. Recursion kills RAM!

Comment: @FèlixGalindoAllué shouldn't tail-end optimization take care of that? Or what specifically do you mean when you're saying that it kills RAM?

Comment: Why rely on compiler optimizations, when you can code better? Why assume the optimizer is on and will be doing the correct procedure? Theoretically, each call in recursion will place data on RAM. Recursion is strictly needed only in tree exploration (e.g. filesystems) or some computational algorithms. For other purposes, it can be a avoided (and make easier the task of the compiler).